# Vue js app is not defined inside the app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined

I have included vue 1.0.18 min.js in a script tag in the html page.

The specialText line doesn't work.

```
var tagApp;

window.onload = function () {
    /* Vue Js App here */
tagApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Title',
    chars: [{
        name: "Jarred",
        attack: 15,
        health: 70,
        special: "Block",
        blockVal: 5,
        specialText: "Passive: Blocks "+ tagApp.chars[0].blockVal +" Damage." 
    // line above: here it doesn't work
    // gives: "can't get chars of undefined"
        }, {
            name: "John"
        }]
     } 
}); // close app
alert(tagApp.chars[0].blockVal); // here it works
getBlockVal(); // here it also works

} // close window.onload

function getBlockVal() {
    var arr = [{
        name: "henry",
        description: "blocks " + tagApp.chars[0].blockVal + " dmg."
    }];
    alert(arr[0].description);
}
```

I've also tried the following inside of specialText:

`this.blockVal` gives undefined.

`this.parent.blockVal` gives undefined.

`this.chars[0].blockVal` says chars is undefined.

`tagApp.chars[0].blockVal` says tagApp is undefined.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update values directly in `data` property. Use `created` lifecycle hook methods to update data object,

```
created: function(){
   this.chars[0].specialText = "Passive: Blocks "+ this.chars[0].blockVal +" Damage."
}
```

About the Vue.js v1 life-cycle hook, https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram. You can try attaching other lifecycle hooks depends on your requirement

Comment: This works. Thanks! But when i change blockVal, specialText still uses the old blockVal value because created only calls it once. So I added a method to update specialText and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `tagApp.chars` objects within it's definition, this is why it is undefined. Remove the line `tagApp.chars[0].blockVal` from the chars definition and everything will work. "You can't use a value of a variable if it is still to be defined".

If you run the following code it works:

```
var tagApp;

window.onload = function () {
    /* Vue Js App here */
tagApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Title',
    chars: [{
        name: "Jarred",
        attack: 15,
        health: 70,
        special: "Block",
        blockVal: 5,
        specialText: "Passive: Blocks " + " Damage." 
    // line above: here it doesn't work
    // gives: "can't get chars of undefined"
        }, {
            name: "John"
        }]
     } 
}); // close app
alert(tagApp.chars[0].blockVal); // here it works
getBlockVal(); // here it also works

} // close window.onload

function getBlockVal() {
    var arr = [{
        name: "henry",
        description: "blocks " + tagApp.chars[0].blockVal + " dmg."
    }];
    alert(arr[0].description);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I now defined blockVal outside of the app and included it in specialText. This works.